# Ajax setInterval is executed twice for manipulated notification

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

First, Let's me explain. I have a page to monitoring my users. In this page, I can see all the request of my users on a table and I can see too the total of the request is in to the server. My question is, How can I make a notification when  a new request is come. I want to make a notification like big window pop-up said "New Request Is Come" and one tone of music that will be play.

This is my code :
**Main page**

```
<!-- start: Header -->


<div class="container-fluid-full">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <noscript>
        <div class="alert alert-block span12">
            <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning!</h4>
            <p>You need to have <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">JavaScript</a> enabled to use this site.</p>
        </div>
        </noscript>

        <!-- start: Content -->


        <!--First indicator-->
        <marquee>Belum Diterima: <span id="request_belum_terima"><?php
                if ($request_belum_terima > 0) {
                    echo $request_belum_terima;
                } else {
                    echo "0 ";
                };
                ?></span> buah Request</marquee>

        <div class="box-header">
            <h2><i class="halflings-icon align-justify"></i><span class="break"></span>Penerimaan Request</h2>
            <div class="box-icon">
                <a href="#" class="btn-minimize"><i class="halflings-icon chevron-up"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Table one-->
        <div class="box-content" id="things_table">
            <?php $this->load->view('view_monitoring_belum_terima'); ?>
        </div>


        <!--Second indicator-->
        <marquee>Belum Selesai: <span><?php
                if ($request_sudah_terima > 0) {
                    echo $request_sudah_terima;
                } else {
                    echo '0 ';
                }
                ?></span> Request</marquee>

        <div class="box-header">
            <h2><i class="halflings-icon align-justify"></i><span class="break"></span>Outstanding Request</h2>
            <div class="box-icon">
                <a href="#" class="btn-minimize"><i class="halflings-icon chevron-up"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!--Table two-->
        <div class="box-content" id="things_table2">
            <?php $this->load->view('view_monitoring_belum_selesai'); ?>
        </div>
    </div><!--/.fluid-container-->
</div><!--/row-->

<?php $this->load->view('view_monitoring_modal') ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>


<!-- start: JavaScript-->
<?php $this->load->view('/include/js.html'); ?>
<!-- end: JavaScript-->
<?php $this->load->view('view_monitoring_js'); ?>
```

I using codeigniter and some jquery to develop my app. So, I solve it one by one.
First, I use the indicator from first marquee. If you can see, there are one ID's jquery on span tag. For ex, First indicator have value 1. So, I use ajax to pool the data from database and check it with old value;
This is the code :

**Controller**

```
public function hitungRequestBelumTerima() {
    $row = $this->model_request->hitungRequestBelumTerima();
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function hitungRequestBelumTerima() {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('is_approved', 1);
    $this->db->where('by_who is not null');
    $this->db->where('it_person is null');

    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_requestfix');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

After that, I write a jquery's code to autorefresh the indicator like this :

```
function refresh() {
    var ini;
    var requestMasuk = $('#request_belum_terima').text();

    setTimeout(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'control_closing/hitungRequestBelumTerima/' ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(obj) {
                if (obj > requestMasuk) {
                    ini = obj;
                    $('#request_belum_terima').text(obj);
                    alert("New request coming");
                }

            }
        }).always(function() {
            $('#request_belum_terima').text(ini);
        }).done(function() {
            $('#request_belum_terima').text(ini);

        });

        $('things_table2').fadeOut('slow').load('<?php ?>').fadeIn('slow');
        refresh();
    }, 20000);
}




$(document).ready(function() {

    refresh();
}
```

It working to refresh, but I dont know, why alert is pop up twice. So, the case is : one new request but two alert of notif has pop-up on one interval. So, in first 10 minutes for ex, Alert is raising. In 20 minutes, alert still coming. But in 30 minute, the alert is not raise. Why the alert raise twice ?

Comment: You want us to debug us such a long code?

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval instead of setTimeout. Here is your ajax function (ajax not tested, as you say its working)

```
function refresh() {
    var ini;
    var requestMasuk = $('#request_belum_terima').text();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'control_closing/hitungRequestBelumTerima/' ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(obj) {
            if (obj > requestMasuk) {
                ini = obj;
                $('#request_belum_terima').text(obj);
                alert("New request coming");
            }

        }
    }).always(function() {
        $('#request_belum_terima').text(ini);
    }).done(function() {
        $('#request_belum_terima').text(ini);

    });

    $('things_table2').fadeOut('slow').load('<?php ?>').fadeIn('slow');
}




$(document).ready(function() {

 setInterval(function () {
    refresh();
 }, 20000);

}
```